# why is my checkbox.change not working (jquery)?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, onclick, onchange

I've done similar things before, click a checkbox then do something (`.parent()` etc) but for some reason it's not registering this time. Can anyone see why?

```
$.each( email_list, function( key, value ) {
$("#email_span").after("<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='member' checked='checked' onclick='check_change(this);' /></td><td>" + value.name + "</td><td>" + value.email + "</td></tr>");
$("#emails").prepend(value.email + ";");
});

$('.member').change(function() {
   alert ("FECK");
   if(this.checked) {
   }
});
```

It is all within the `$(document).ready` block. I've got it working with a function call but was curious why the jQuery `.change` wasn't working?

Comment: HTML please. Any errors occured?

Comment: Why are you using `check_change` inline click handler? Use `$("tr").on("change",":checkbox[name='member']",function(){` instead of `$('.member').change(function() {`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

For dynamically created element you have to use [`event delegation`](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), if you want to select by an attribute you can use an [`attribute equals selector`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

Code:

```
$(document).on("change", "input[name='member']", function () {
    alert("FECK");
    if (this.checked) {}
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2fepaf0y/

Answer (score 12):

If the element has the 'change' event bound and if you need to fire the 'change' event after changing the checkbox property you can use the alt workaround below:

If you want to check:

```
$('#MyCheckbox input:checkbox').prop('checked', false).click();
```

If you want to uncheck:

```
$('#MyCheckbox input:checkbox').prop('checked', true).click();
```

## Summary

it's using a reverse process. for the first one it will make sure the checkbox property is NOT checked, then it will trigger the click which will change the checkbox property to 'checked' then it will fire the 'change' event - if it's bound.

Comment: Superb solution! +1

Answer (score 3):

You shoud use this way :

```
$('body').on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]',function (e) {
//what ever you wanna do
});
```

(Because google search shows this page for another issues It make sense to explain more)

And If you want to **check**  and  **uncheck** programmatically with raising **change** event you should add **.change()** at the end of lines like these :

```
$('checkboxGroups').prop('checked', true).change();
$('checkboxGroups').prop('checked', false).change();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using [*class*](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) selector, but you don't have class called `.member`. You need to use [*attribute equal elector*](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) instead:

```
$('input[name=member]').change...
```

Answer (score 1):

Give your `checkboxes` a class say `'check'` and then try event delegation as shown below :-

```
$(document).on('change','.check',function() {
   alert ("FECK");
  if(this.checked) {
   alert ("checked");
  }
});
```

OR

```
$(document).on('change','input[name="member"]',function() {
   alert ("FECK");
  if(this.checked) {
   alert ("checked");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Delegate the `change` event

```
$("tr").on("change","input[name='member']",function(){
alert ("FECK");
   if(this.checked) {
    //do other stuff
   }
})
```

Comment: there is no class 'member' in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding the 'change' listener inside your $.each loop.. Maybe just make the change listener more specific like:

```
$('#email_span').on('change', '.member', function(){ 
    console.log('you hit it'); if($(this).prop('checked')){
    console.log('it\'s checked');
  } 
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Try adding such scripts inside:

```
$(document).ready(function () {});
```

function.

Comment: I doubt that this helps or even can work at all. To convince me otherwise please explain how this works and why it helps with the described problem.